# Array dentro de array... usando array_push

Tags: php, array

Para fins de estudo e melhor compreensão estou tentando fazer um array dentro de outro array adicionando valores usando o array_push, segue meu exemplo:

```
<?php

$ar1 = array();
array_push($ar1, 1, 2, 3, 4);

foreach($ar1 as $ar) {
    $ar2 = array();
    array_push($ar2, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    array_push($ar1, $ar2);

    foreach($ar1 as $ar) {
        echo $ar . "";
    }
}
```

***Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\EstudoPHP\arrays.php on line 12
Array1234***

Conforme erro, não estou entendo a lógica correta para isso.

Comment: `echo $ar . "";` é misturar array com string..., faça `var_dump($ar);` em vez desse `echo`

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o que você procura seja algo assim:

```
$first = array('doh', 'ray', 'me');
$second = array('fah', 'soh', 'lah', 'te', 'do');

echo "Union: ", var_export($first + $second, true), "\n";
echo "Merge: ", var_export(array_merge($first, $second), true), "\n";

// array_push returns int, not an array:
array_push($first, $second);
echo "Push: ", var_export($first, true), "\n";
```

Saída:

```
Union: array (
  0 => 'doh',
  1 => 'ray',
  2 => 'me',
  3 => 'te',
  4 => 'do',
)
Merge: array (
  0 => 'doh',
  1 => 'ray',
  2 => 'me',
  3 => 'fah',
  4 => 'soh',
  5 => 'lah',
  6 => 'te',
  7 => 'do',
)
Push: array (
  0 => 'doh',
  1 => 'ray',
  2 => 'me',
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'fah',
    1 => 'soh',
    2 => 'lah',
    3 => 'te',
    4 => 'do',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Nossa, bastava usar o array_merge então, interessante. Vou analisar bem isso, valeu. Mas é porque eu também queria montar uma matriz.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você deve estar tentando algo neste sentido:

```
$ar1 = array(1 => array(), 2 => array(), 3 => array(), 4 => array());

$size = count($ar1);
/** Adiciona um array novo com os valores 5, 6,7 e 8 a cada posicao do array $ar1*/
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $ar1[$i] = array(5, 6, 7, 8);
}

foreach ($ar1 as $chave => $valor) {
  echo 'Mostrando array ' . $chave . '<br />';
  foreach ($valor as $valor2) {
    echo $valor . ', ';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assim:
//Array para gerar novos índices
$pos1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

//Função [array_fill]
$pos=array_fill(0,10,$pos1);

Saída:
array (size=10)
  0 => 
    array (size=10)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 2
      2 => int 3
      3 => int 4
      4 => int 5
      5 => int 6
      6 => int 7
      7 => int 8
      8 => int 9
      9 => int 10
  1 => 
    array (size=10)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 2
      2 => int 3
      3 => int 4
      4 => int 5
      5 => int 6
      6 => int 7
      7 => int 8
      8 => int 9
      9 => int 10
  2 => ..........